# me devuelve un valor sin decimales, pero tiene decimales

Tags: mysql, laravel, float, double

bien no se como preguntar realmente en esta ocasión, el problema que tengo es que estoy guardando datos numéricos, donde todos los campos son `float`, en la `BDD` me los guarda con los decimales, pero al querer mostrarlos no me muestra los decimales, solo si este es `> 0.1`

ejemplo:

`BDD  =>  retorna`

`20.00 => 20`

`20.40 => 20.4`

`20.44 => 20.44`

Bien en el lado izquierdo es como se guarda y en el lado derecho es como me los muestra, lo raro es que en el gestor segun el tipo del campo es `double` pero los estoy "declarando" `float`

```
 Schema::create('tabla', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->bigIncrements('id');
     $table->float('valor1', 8,2);
     $table->float('valor2', 8,2);
     $table->float('valor3', 8,2);
 });
```

cuando tenia los campos tipo `decimal` si los mostraba bien, aún siendo `0.00`, por que con `float` no?

el `"cotejamiento"` podría tener algo que ver con este problema ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No veo clara tu duda 20.4 = 20.40 los ceros a la derecha del último valor no nulo en una expansión decimal carecen de significado. Las lecturas **veinte punto cuatro** y **veinte punto cuarenta** son abuso de lenguaje en ambos casos debe leerse **veinte y 4 décimos** o **veinte y cuarenta centésimos** que son expresiones equivalentes. Si necesitas que la **vista** muestre el cero de la expansión (que se muestren los centésimos) tu mismo debes **formatearla**

Comment: la duda es por que me esta enviando a la vista un `20.4` si en la `BDD` esta guardada como `20.40`, osea los decimales no los muestra correctamente, esto no pasaba cuando el tipo del campo era `decimal` y como lo formateo, en la vista? si es así mejor lo dejo como estaba.

Comment: Tal vez, de alguna forma extraña, tu base de datos está formateando la salida. La única forma (que yo conozco) de ver un número 20.4 como 20.40, es que lo almacenes como varchar.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras, con tipo `decimal`, si me muestra correctamente.

Comment: Cuando en BD la columna es decimal, te está devolviendo un string (php), por eso puedes ver ceros sin valor, pero cuando pones float, te devuelve un float (php). Como te dicen en el primer comentario, si quieres imprimir un float en pantalla y que muestre ceros sin valor, debes formatearlo tú mismo.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, si entendí eso pero lo que no quería era eso andar formateando, pero ya tocara, gracias!

Comment: Bueno, puedes dejarlo en decimal en BD y manejarte con strings en vez de float. Si son número solo para mostrar en pantalla y no tienes que hacer cálculos no hay problema. Pero son números que usas para hacer cálculos, esa es la forma, te manejas con un tipo de dato que corresponda con números, y lo formateas sólo al momento de mostrarlo en pantalla.

Comment: Por supuesto, con `decimal` lo formatea, pero mencionaste float. Tal vez debí hacer esa aclaración.